# Dockerizing a flask resfull application and running on ngnix

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to dockerize a flask restful application and run it on ngnix proxy server,

I have one Dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM python:3.7
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /app/thermo-restful
WORKDIR /app/thermo-restful
COPY requirements.txt /app/thermo-restful
COPY main.py /app/thermo-restful
EXPOSE 9000
RUN ["pip", "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]
CMD ["uwsgi", "--socket", "0.0.0.0:9000", "--protocol", "http", "-w", "main:app"]
FROM nginx:latest
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

The deault.conf for ngnix is as follow:

```
server {
  listen 8000;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://server:9000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

I then built image and run it using below command:

```
docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name image-name-app image-name
```

But the image doesn't run properly and looking at the logs of the container it gives me below information:

```
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: error: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2020/08/14 08:50:39 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "server" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:4
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "server" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:4
```

Can anyone point me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're trying to run uWSGI and NGINX in the same container.  Each should have it's own container, tied together with docker-compose.  Testdriven.io did a tutorial on this which has a [repo](https://github.com/testdrivenio/flask-on-docker/) which sets this out better.

Comment: why, they shoud have seprate containers?

Comment: Check this manual for creating docker image for flask - https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask-docker

Comment: Starting just Python is used only for development. For production with many possible requests you have to use uWSGI. So there is some burden to set it up so.

Comment: @Mahi [Why it is recommended to run only one process in a container?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container)